# Sum of a sum [algorithm design and analysis]

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, computational-complexity

I'm studying the algorithm analysis of one piece of code, and I have to find the `big-O` notation of the sum of a sum.

$$g(n)=\sum^{n}_{i=0}\left(\sum^{n}_{j=i+1}O(1)\right)$$
$O(1)= c\times1$, thus
$$g(n)=\sum^{n}_{i=0}\left[\sum^{n}_{j=i+1}(c\times 1)\right]$$

But I can't take it from here.

Any suggestion? thanks!

Comment: $O(1)= c\times1$ is misleading. Stick to the definition : $f(n) = O(1) \Leftrightarrow |f(n)| \le \; c \text{ for all }n>n_0$.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply write $c$ instead of $(c \times 1)$, and then evaluate the sum. What kind of function of $n$ do you get?

Answer (score 1):

What is $\sum_{j=i+1}^{n} c$? It evaluates to $c(n-i)$. We can then pull out the $c$ and evaluate $c\sum_{i=1}^{n} (n-i)$. You should be able to take it from here.

Note: With complexities, you can drop the constant. So with $O(1)$, you can simply replace it with $1$, and it won't change the complexity.

Comment: Are yo sure that $\sum^{n}_{j=i+1}=\sum^{n}_{i=1}(n-i+1)$?

Comment: That was a small error on my part. Thanks for the catch. Even if it did, the +1 term would come out as a constant at the end and could be ignored.

Comment: $\sum^{n}_{i=1}1 = n$, so, it can not be ignored, your first sum it's ok. But my question is: what is the name of the property that you're using here?